# Play Framework POST endpoint returning Time Out - 504

Tags: nginx, playframework, connection-timeout, http-status-code-504

I'm running a REST API production built on Play Framework 2.5.10. Its running through NGINX reverse routing, I'm able to reach all GET end points but I get a timeout on all POST endpoint, all this consume JSON.

Please note that on the development environment its working fine and i'm able to reach all this endpoints but on production I get a timeout on POST whether by connecting through IP or via reverse route DNS.

Any pointers in resolving this is highly appreciated.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name subdomain.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_connect_timeout       300;
    proxy_send_timeout          300;
    proxy_read_timeout          300;
    send_timeout                300;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   Host      $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000;
  }   
}
```

Route trying to access

```
POST    /auth                       controllers.Application.authenticate()
```

Do i need to define all the routes on nginx?

Added auth Code

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public Result authenticate(){
    JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();
    EncryptUtil secure = null;
    secure=EncryptUtil.getSecurityUtility();
    String command = "login";
    String logincommand = json.findPath("command").asText();
    if (logincommand.equals(command)){
        String email = json.findPath("email").textValue();
        String password = json.findPath("password").textValue();
        Logger.info("Passwords::"+password+"\t"+secure.getEncryptedUserPassword(password.trim()));
        UserAccount user=UserAccount.findByEmail(email);
        if(user!=null){
            if(!(secure.getDecryptedUserPassword(user.password).equals(password))){
                return status(400,"Invalid credentials");
            }else {
                if (user.accountstatus == Boolean.FALSE){
                    result.put("error","Account Deactivated Contact Admin");
                    return status(400,"Account Deactivated Contact Admin");

                } else {
                    String authToken = user.createToken();
                    ObjectNode authTokenJson = Json.newObject();
                    authTokenJson.put(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken);
                    response().setCookie(Http.Cookie.builder(AUTH_TOKEN, authToken).withSecure(ctx().request().secure()).build());
                    JsonNode userJson = Json.toJson(user);
                    return status(200,userJson);
                }

            }

        }
        else{
            result.put("Error", "Invalid User");
            Logger.info(result.toString());
            return status(400,"Invalid Credentials");
        }
    } else{
        return globalFunctions.returnBadRequest(command);
    }

}
```

Comment: Share the method for the POST action (in your controller) and also the relevant section of nginx conf.

Comment: @marcospereira i've posted the info you requested for.

Comment: Can you confirm that the POST requests are actually arriving in your application? Could you also post the code for `authenticate` method?

Comment: @marcospereira it reaches but really takes long

Comment: @marcospereira code posted above

Comment: "it reaches but really takes long" so, could it be that response (and you have a connection to the DB inside the method) is slower that 300 seconds? Try to measure the time intervals for GET responses, and for access the DB inside a POST method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your POST request bodies are large and the connection is slow and/or the medium where nginx stores temporary files is slow, this may be caused by the request buffering that nginx does by default.

In its log file, nginx should also warn about large bodies being cached to disk.

If that is your problem, you can disable buffering requests with the following directive, which is valid inside `http`, `server` and `location` stanzas:

```
proxy_request_buffering off;
```

Note that this will preclude failover to backup servers in some cases, in case you're using that feature. If not, you're fine.

See also http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_request_buffering

If you want, you can disable request buffering selectively, for instance only for certain `location`s or just for the `POST` method.